# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mport pandas as pd\r'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mport pandas as pd\r'

but not getting any line in the source code 'mport pandas as pd/r'

This is code part nothing here like mport not even in the other file that is imported in the code.

```
{ 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
import pickle
from utils import display_img

data = pd.read_pickle('pickles/dataclean.py')

stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
def nlp_preprocessing(total_text, index, column):
    if type(total_text) is not int:
        string = ""
        for words in total_text.split():
            # remove the special chars in review like '"#$@!%^&*()_+-~?>
```

dataclean.py

```
{import pandas as pd
# loading the data using pandas' read_json file.
data = pd.read_json('data/tops_fashion.json')
data = data.loc[~data['formatted_price'].isnull()]#this will remove data with no price
data =data.loc[~data['color'].isnull()]#remove data with no color
#print(sum(data.duplicated('title')))#tell about dubplicate  
from remove_duplicate import remove_dup1,remove_dup2   
data=remove_dup1(data)#removes adjacent sorted same title
data=remove_dup2(data)#this will take time approx half hour
data.to_pickle('pickels/dataclean')}
```

nothing is in dataclean.py related to mport even i searched it on google but no detail is available related to this error 
Generally "mport" kind of error related to syntax error but no such error mentioned on other side it tried to search for the related module

this code is related to product recommendation system

Expected Result: Should run smoothly
//Error code
Actual Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recom.py", line 11, in <module>
    data = pd.read_pickle('pickles/dataclean.py')
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 180, in read_pickle
    return try_read(path, encoding='latin1')
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 175, in try_read
    lambda f: pc.load(f, encoding=encoding, compat=True))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 149, in read_wrapper
    return func(f)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 175, in <lambda>
    lambda f: pc.load(f, encoding=encoding, compat=True))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py", line 212, in load
    return up.load()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1050, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1309, in load_inst
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py", line 135, in find_class
    return super(Unpickler, self).find_class(module, name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1388, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mport pandas as pd\r'}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but why is it saying 'mport' instead of 'import'?

Comment: What's inside dataclean.py?

Comment: @marcoromelli I have added the dataclean.py code

Comment: Getting "Invalid syntax" on your file. So this is not your file exactly as written. Remove the curly braces nevertheless, they are invalid Python.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev their is no syntex error as all the code mentioned is sytex error free I alrdy checked it

Comment: I've no idea what you are trying to do but loading a Python file as a pickle is not gonna work.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   File "recom.py", line 11, in <module>
>     data = pd.read_pickle('pickles/dataclean.py')
>
> //dataclean.py
>
> {import pandas as pd
> ```

You are trying to load a Python file as a pickle. Python and pickle are two completely different formats, so this is never gonna work. I don't know what you are trying to do, or who suggested you to put Python code into curly braces to boot, but this is one of the craziest things I've ever seen people try.